# Stripe Integration with Devise - You passed an empty string for 'card'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, stripe-payments

I previously fixed my models/user.rb file along with my layout/applications.html.erb file and was able to process credit cards with Stripe.

However when I tried again the next day it suddenly stopped working. I got the error:

**Stripe::InvalidRequestError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create**

*You passed an empty string for 'card'. We assume empty values are an attempt to unset a parameter; however 'card' cannot be unset. You should remove 'card' from your request or supply a non-empty value*

Here are both files any ideas why it's not working? Let me know if you need more info from me

Here is the link to the repository as well - https://github.com/matthewwoo/boldesttea

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

     #validates :name, presence: true
     after_create :create_a_customer

     attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

     def create_a_customer
             token = self.stripe_card_token

             customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
                            :card => token,
                            :plan => 1,
                            :email => self.email
            )               
     end

end
```

layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Boldesttea</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v1/", type: 'text/javascript' %>
    <%= javascript_tag "alert('#{Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]}')", type: 'text/javascript' %>  
    <%= javascript_tag "Stripe.publishableKey = '#{Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]}';", type: 'text/javascript' %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>        
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    </head>
    <body>
    <div class='key'>
     <%= puts Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>
    </div>
    <%= render 'layouts/header'%>
     <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
         <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
     <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: It comes from the app/views/devise/registration/new.html.erb

Comment: Here's a link to the file: https://github.com/matthewwoo/boldesttea/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

Comment: It seems that sometimes it does and sometime it doesn't, so it might be something to do with an initializer...

Comment: By the way here is my controller for charges - https://github.com/matthewwoo/boldesttea/blob/master/app/controllers/charges_controller.rb

Comment: How would you go about debugging that?

Comment: You don't have a users controller. Are you able to successfully create a user?

Comment: Yes I am able to successfully create a user